# How to download a page in Angular 8 with TS in pdf format

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-conversion

this is the function i'm calling for downloading the page

```
printComponent(cmpName) {
let printContents = document.getElementById(cmpName).innerHTML;
let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

window.print();


document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;}
```

it is working but a intermediate step comes. the project requires direct download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/)

```
export class AppComponent {
  generatePdf(cmpName){
  const documentDefinition = { content: document.getElementById(cmpName).innerHTML 
 };
  pdfmake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open();
 }
}
```